# How to find base address of same char in string array using pointers in C language?

Tags: c, c-strings

I input a string and then try to find an address of a `char` within the string but the problem is that I am unable to find the address of the same `char` in the string using pointers.

For example when input is `"ALLEN"` I need the addresses of both `'L'`s but my program only prints the address of the first `'L'`.

I tried `if ... else` and a `for`-loop but I can't solve the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 


main() 
{ 
    char a, str[81], *ptr;

    printf("\nEnter a sentence:");
    gets(str); 

    printf("\nEnter character to search for:");
    a = getchar(); 
    ptr = strchr(str,a);

     /* return pointer to char*/ 

    printf( "\nString starts at address: %d",str);
    printf("\nFirst occurrence of the character (%c) is at address: %d ", a,ptr);  
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *"return a pointer to char"*.  your code really isn't returning anything.  also, `a` needs to be `int` not `char` because `getchar()` returns an `int`.  Also, [don't use gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  It is dangerous and has been deprecated and even the documentation says don't use it.

Comment: Your `main()` has no return type. When a function doesn't take any parameters it's parameter list should be `void`: `int main(void)`. Also, the correct conversion specifier for pointer values for `*printf()` is `%p` not `%d`.

Comment: @MFisherKDX it was deprecated between 1999 and 2011, it is now removed

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly:

To find additional occurrences of the same character, just look for them *after*  the last known occurrence. So, you would write something like this:

```
{
    const char* next_occurrence = strchr(str, a);
    while (next_occurrence != NULL) {
        printf(
            "Character %c occurs in string \"%s\" at position %p\n",
            a, str, next_occurrence - str);
        next_occurrence = strchr(next_occurrence + 1, a);
    }
}
```

You'll note that `next_occurrence + 1` is the address of the first character after the occurrence we've just found.

Comment: suggest: *just look for them from right after the last known occurrence.* *~>* "just look for them starting one to the right after the last known occurrence."

Answer (score 1):

Just call `strchr` again:

```
ptr = strchr(str,a);
if (ptr != NULL)
    ptr2 = strchr (ptr + 1, a);
```

Notice the first parameter to `strchr` is `ptr + 1`, so we start searching with the character after the one we already found.